# Javascript .innerHTML resets my <input type="file">

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I have a problem concerning multiple file uploads in javascript. I am trying to create my own multiple file upload by dynamically adding inputs. This is all easy as pie, but the problem is that whenever I add a new , my previous input-fields of the type "file" get reset.

If I remove the last lines of code where I alter the innerHTML of my parent div, the values of my  do not get reset. Does anyone know how this problem can be solved? The javascript code can be found below. Thanks in advance.

```
if(document.getElementById("upload_queue").innerHTML.indexOf(_item) == -1)
{
    var _row = "<tr id='queue_row_" + items_in_queue + "'>";
    _row += "<td>";
    _row += "<div class='remove_uploaded_image' onclick='remove_from_queue(" + items_in_queue + ")'></div>";
    _row += "</td>";
    _row += "<td>";
    _row += _item;
    _row += "</td>";
    _row += "</tr>";

    document.getElementById("upload_queue").innerHTML += _row;
    document.getElementById("upload_image_" + items_in_queue).style.display = "none";

    items_in_queue++;

    document.getElementById("uploader_holder").innerHTML += 
        '<input id="upload_image_' + items_in_queue + 
        '" name="upload_image_' + items_in_queue + '" accept="image/jpeg" type="file"' + 
        'onchange="add_to_upload_queue()" style="display: inline;" />';
}
```

Comment: It gets reset because you are effectively removing all elements from the parent and creating new ones.

Comment: I was unaware that the += operand removes everything before adding the new element. I thought javascript just appended the line of code at the back of the div, as you would expect when using +=

Comment: `innerHTML` is doing much more than just appending HTML as string. It takes the new value, parses it as DOM elements and appends (sets) them to the parent. `+=` is basically the same as `foo.innerHTML = foo.innerHTML + '....'`. I.e. the content of `foo` is "serialized", the new content is appended and then everything is assigned to `innerHTML` (which as already mentioned removes all children and parses the passed value).

Comment: I didn't know that. Learned something new today ^^ Thanks for this explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah... you're going to want to use appendChild instead of modifying the inner HTML:

```
var myInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
// do stuff to my input

var myContainer = document.getElementById("uploader_holder");
myContainer.appendChild(myInput);
```

That's the general gist of what you have to do - let me know if you need somethign more specific, but it looks like you've got a good hold on JS already...  You're going to want to do that in almost all cases rather than setting inner HTML...  So, building your TR as well...  you'll have to append the TD to the TR, you'll have to append the TD with your input, you'll have to append your targeted table with the TR, etc.